# for display:table - tfooter or footer

Tags: html, css

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="page-not-found">
                <div class="error">
                    <h2>Error</h2>
                    <p>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
                    <p>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
                    <footer class="footer">Some text</footer>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.page-not-found {
  background: url(../images/page-not-found_bg.png) left 20px no-repeat;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff0;
}
.page-not-found div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

What tag i have to use for footer - footer or tfooter?
and 
Does it normal to insert footer into div.error?

Comment: if it's HTML5, use `<footer>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The footer tag is available for you to use as the footer to a document or section, most notably like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    This is the footer information
   </footer>
</body>
```

You can also use footer as the child of a sectioning element.
The element tfoot is for tables only.

To answer your question, yes you can technically use a footer tag, but it might not be the best choice depending on your content.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp